# Setting GIF image blockes UI when updating performed in background or main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, gif

I'm setting a GIF image within a `UIImageView` using an `objective-c` library [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage). I'm currently facing an issue where the UI is being blocked while the GIF image is being loaded (***touches not registered on overlay `UIView` which is presented in front of the image, overlay view is hidden/shown on tap***). I've tried updating the image on a background thread and on a main thread, results remain the same. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Or any alternatives? (PS. I also have a `UITextView` with detects links, doubt that's important)

**UITableViewCell**

```
        //Main Thread blocks UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
       cell.shotImg.setShotImage(self.shots[self.currentIndex])
         })
    //Background thread also blocks ui. See code below for background thread function
  backgroundThread(0.1, completion: {
      cell.shotImg.setShotImage(self.shots[self.currentIndex])
         })
```

**FLAnimatedImage Extension**

```
extension FLAnimatedImageView{

    func setRegularImage(url: String){
        self.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
    }

    func setGIFImage(url: String){
        let animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)!)
        self.animatedImage = animatedImage
    }

    func setShotImage(shot: Shots){
        var url: String!
        if(shot.images.hidpi != nil){
            url = shot.images.hidpi
        }else{
            url = shot.images.normal
        }

        if(shot.animated!){
            self.setGIFImage(url)
        }else{
            self.setRegularImage(shot.images.normal)
        }
    }
}
```

**Background thread**

```
func backgroundThread(delay: Double = 0.0, background: (() -> Void)? = nil, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue), 0)) {
        if(background != nil){ background!(); }

        let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if(completion != nil){ completion!(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is this:

```
 NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url))
```

That's not how you download something (if that's what you're doing). Use NSURLSession.

Comment: I was simply following the examples given by the library (It did seem strange when transferred to swift). Thanks for your help!! I'll try downloading the image using `Alamofire` or `AlamofireImage` (i really don't like using `NSURLSession`)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have static cells, you cannot update the cell directly in a background thread as you are doing. While you scroll, the table view will reuse cells off screen for those newly appearing. By the time the background task finishes, the cell is likely to belong to another row.

Instead you should store the image in an array when the task finishes, and then call reloadData (on the main thread). Then cellForRowAtIndexPath should display the image from the array, or fetch it in the background if it hasn't been fetched yet (which will trigger the reloadData to display it when finished).